# Infinite Sum Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

What value does the infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^4} $ converge to? I know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} $ converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but I simply do not have a clue as to where to start in order to find the value to which the first sum converges. (Sorry. I had to edit the question; my problem did not involve $\frac{1}{k^3}$ but rather $\frac{1}{k^4}$.)

Comment: Mathematicians have yet to find a closed-form value for $\zeta(3)$. If you are interested, do some research on the Riemann Zeta function. The answer to your question is the number $\approx 1.202$, which is also called "Apéry's Constant".

Comment: Keep in mind: Apéry didn't invent it, he proved it's irrational.

Comment: Now, it converges to $\zeta(4)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with contour integration and the residue theorem?  If so, evaluate $\oint_{|z|=N+1/2}\frac{\cot(z)}{z^4}\,dz$ and watch the "magical" appearance of the series of interest.

Comment: That may be too complicated. One could also compare the partial fraction decomposition of $\tan x$ with the Taylor series.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Not at all.  Another way is through Fourier Series analysis and exploitation of Parseval's theorem.